# HOW TO DELETE A SPECIFIC CHARACTER IN EACH ROW OF A SPECIFIC COLUMN IN A DATAFRAME

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, row

the first column of my dataframe has the following data
Datetime
0   2022-06-01T00:00:00.0
1   2022-06-01T00:01:00.0
.
.
.
the rows in my dataframe are 100.000
does anybody knows how can i delete the character T in each row so that the output be
0   2022-06-01 00:00:00.0
1   2022-06-01 00:01:00.0

Comment: Please don't use all uppercase letter in the title.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
df["time"] = df["time"].str.replace("T"," ")
```

Comment: Can you assign this asnwer as the correct one.